# Calculate the area of the parallelogram given two vectors in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have two 3D vectors represented by two numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
v1 = np.array([2, -3, 5])
v2 = np.array([1, 4, -2])
```

I want to calculate the area of parallelogram, in which the two adjacent sides are given by `v1` and `v2`. I write the following code:

```
import math
area = math.sqrt((v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0])**2
               + (v1[1] * v2[2] - v1[2] * v2[1])**2
               + (v1[0] * v2[2] - v1[2] * v2[0])**2)

print(area)
# 19.949937343260004
```

The code is working fine, but what is the numpyic way to code this? I'm not familiar with numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area of parallelogram can be calculated by  the [*norm*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html?highlight=norm#numpy.linalg.norm) of [the cross product](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html) of the two vectors. As you can see from cross product [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product), the norm of cross product is basically ***|a||b|sin(θ)*** which is one of the common used area formulas for [parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram).

```
np.linalg.norm(np.cross(v1, v2))
# 19.949937343260004
```